# On Elliot's classification of AF-algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, k-theory

I have two questions with a relation to Elliot's classification of Approximately Finite $C*$-algebras (from now on referred to as AF-algebras).

Elliot's classical result yields that whenever $A$ and $B$ are AF-algebras and $\sigma \colon K_0(A) \to K_0(B)$ is a an isomorphism of scaled ordered $K_0$-groups, then this isomorphism induces a $*$-ismorphism $\varphi \colon A \to B$. Furthermore, it holds that $K_0(\varphi) = \sigma$. A proof of this is to be found in Blackadar's "$K_0$-theory for operator algebras".

I have been told that the above result is in fact slightly stronger. Namely that if $\tau \colon A \to B$ is another $*$-isomorphism then $K_0(\varphi) = K_0(\tau) = \sigma$, meaning that the lift is in fact uniquely determined. How does one obtain this fact?

My second question is of a slightly different kind. I have found a result saying that whenever one have $*$-homomorphisms $\iota_1, \iota_2 \colon C \to D$ where $C$ and $D$ are finite-dimensional $C*$-algebras, then $\iota_1$ are $\iota_2$ are unitarily equivalent. Again, I have been told that this may be generalised in the following sense: If we instead suppose for $C$ and $D$ to be AF-algebras, then $\iota_1$ and $\iota_2$ are approximately unitarily equivalent. It is my impression that Wikipedia mentions this result [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximately_finite-dimensional_C*-algebra), but I cannot find any reference for it. Does anyone have a reference or an idea as to how one obtains the result?

Answer (score 1):

In your second question, I guess you mean $\iota_1,\iota_2 \colon C \to D$ are such that $K_0(\iota_1) = K_0(\iota_2)$.

Note that the following is true (Lemma 7.3.2. in "An Introducion to K-theory for C*-algebras" by Rordam, Larsen, Lausten)

**Lemma.** Assume $A$ is finite dimensional and $B$ is a unital C*-algebra with the cancellation property (for example an AF-algebra). Then the following holds: If $\varphi, \psi \colon A \to B$ are $*$-hom., then $K_0(\varphi) = K_0(\psi)$ if and only if there exists a unitary $u \in B$ such that $\varphi = u^* \psi(-) u$.

This lemma  immediately answers your second question.

It also answers your first question: Whenever $A,B$ are AF algebras and $\varphi,\psi \colon A \to B$ induce the same map on $K$-theory, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are approximately unitarily equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you more specifically specify why $K(\varphi) = K(\psi)$ whenever $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are approximately unitarily equivalent. I have difficulties formalizing that specific implication.

Comment: First assume that $A,B$ are unital. If $\psi,\varphi : A \to B$ are approx. unitarily equivalent, then there exist unitaries $u_n$ in $B$ such that $\varphi(-) = \lim_{\mathbb N} u_n^* \psi (- ) u_n$. Therefore, if $p$ is a projection in $A$, you get that  the distance of $\varphi(p)$ and $u_n^*\psi(p)u_n$ is less then one, for large $n$. In particular $\varphi(p)$ is equivalent to $u_n^* \psi(p) u_n$, which itself is equivalent to $\psi(p)$. Therefore, $\varphi(p)$ is equivalent to $\psi(p)$ for all projections $p \in A$.